# Where to host private CartoDB/Leaflet web app

Tags: google-maps, leaflet, carto, hosting, sharepoint

I am looking for suggestions/recommendations on where to host my cartodb/leaflet map site.

It needs to be private with authorized users and have a document management system.

So, I was thinking sharepoint online 2013 so I can use a sharepoint subsite to view the map and take advantage of the document management and sharing as well as their tasks and calendar parts.

Or I could use google app engine to host the map site and google apps for business to handle the document management, email, calendar, tasks... Both of these paths are pretty pricey to share the map and docs with 15-60 users.

Is putting this site in the cloud on google app engine or amazon cloud overkill for such a small app? will sharepoint online 2013 be able to handle this app with 15-60 users?

Is there a better option out there like website hosting from godaddy and huddle for doc management? Please let me know if you have any advice. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's only for 50 people you can share it with Dropbox and it'll work.

Another option that is a little complex, but very fast, is [using S3 to host a static website](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html).

I think Dropbox would suit you better. You can do cool things then, like:

1. it's versioned for a month (you can restore previous versions via the Dropbox web-interface).
2. you can edit the file locally, and it'll be uploaded to the link that you shared automatically
3. if you use the command 'python -m SimpleHTTPServer' in the folder the file is stored in, you can edit it while viewing it properly in your web-browser.

Quick edit: you can use [GitHub](http://pages.github.com/) to host live files too, and then it'll be properly version-controlled. If you pay money you can make it private too.

EDIT: coming back to this 3 years later, I now do NOT think Dropbox is a good idea! Either use [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/) or S3. Note that with S3 including CloudFront you can have a static site that can handle mega traffic, and using AWS Certificate Manager you can have HTTPS for free too!

Answer (score 0):

You can use for example site44.com. They host Dropbox folders, but offer also a password protection for the website. I like that you can map your domain to the service. The sync from Dropbox to the server is sometimes a bit slow, but overall it works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Use [openshift](https://www.openshift.com). This way you can scale if/when you outgrow cartoDB

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at https://getgeodb.com which is hosted services for CartoDB

Answer (score -1):

What you need is :

**System requirements**

Besides the OS version mentioned in the introduction, there are some systems requirements needed before starting with the installation of the stack. Also this process assumes that you have enough permissions in the system to run successfully most part of the commands of this doc.

**System locales**

Installations assume you use UTF8. You can set the locale by doing this:

```
sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
sudo update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

**Build essentials**

Althoug we try to maintain packaged versions of almost every part of the stack, there are some parts like gems or npm packages that need some development tools in the system in order to compile. You can install all the needed build tools by doing this. After weeks research I choose this hosting provider https://www.tmdhosting.com. I have asked the chat support about the requirements and they happen to suit my need. After 2 months hosting I have some hiccups with them but overall they are ok. Support is polite and help me with the full installation of the app.

Comment: If you are going to do a partial cut-and-paste from the [CartoDB manual](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/blob/78922fb2e887ceda09f1acfd536ba2839d3ea08c/doc/manual/source/install.rst) followed by a link to a hosting provider, you should at least clarify which parts are from official documentation and which parts are your own suggestion. It looks an awful lot like spam, otherwise.