# Host LeafLet Page on Dropbox

Tags: leaflet, dropbox

Can anyone provide me with some information on hosting a LeafLet web map, created with the `QGIS2Leaf` plugin for QGIS, on Dropbox. I have used Droppages, however the webmap does not come in, it is a totally blank page. When I preview the page as a file, it is an interactive webmap. I have looked at the following post:
    [Where to host private CartoDB/Leaflet web app](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/88276/where-to-host-private-cartodb-leaflet-web-app)  however it does not provide any insight.

Comment: client side scripts only http://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/host-websites-with-dropbox no CORS either

Comment: yes it would be interesting to know what errors you are getting, I suspect something cross-domain blocking...

Comment: Any thoughts on locations where I can host this for free? I have had similar issues using GitHub